Connection Pixhawk with Missionplanner via Telem Ports
I have a USB-TTL cable with only the RX, TX, and ground pins correctly connected. I want to connect it to MissionPlanner on Windows with telem ports, similar to how we connect using a micro USB to USB cable and see various data like altitude, location, etc.
I have a Pixhawk Cube Black. I followed the setup section found in the ArduPilot documentation, but I can’t establish a connection. I suspect it’s because there are no RTS and CTS pins, but I’m not sure because I’m very new to this field. How can I establish this connection without RTS and CTS pins? Could you help me with this?
From what I can see on the oscilloscope, there is continuous data coming from the TX pin. I believe this data is the heartbeat signal. However, when I tried to read the COM port using Python, I see an empty byte array.

I reversed the direction of the RX and TX pins, and the problem was resolved. The RX and TX pins you find in the pinout diagram for the USB-TTL Cable online are not the it's own RX-TX; they are for the device you're connecting to.
